# Where is the source code of VOP_WRITE_APV()?

Tags: freebsd

Who knows where the source code VOP_WRITE_APV() in FreeBSD? How to append to the file automatically, without calculating the offset using the vn_rdwr(9) in FreeBSD?

Comment: If not even google can find the identifier `VOP_WRITE_AVP`, that strongly suggest it does not exist. Why do you think it exists?

Comment: @Jens Sorry, VOP_WRITE_APV().

Answer (score 2):

These calls are generated from kern/vnode_if.src. The generated file is under the obj tree in kernel dir under the name vnode_if.c